# Evaluating $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{0} xe^{x(1-i\omega)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, complex-numbers

> Evaluating $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{0} xe^{x(1-i\omega)} dx$

I did integration by parts and got

$$I = \frac{xe^{x(1 - i\omega)}}{1-i\omega} \bigg \rvert_{-\infty}^{0} - \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{x(1-i\omega)}}{1- i\omega} dx$$

The problem is I don't know what happens when I plug in $-\infty$ in the first term.

I know that $\lim \limits_{x \to-\infty} xe^{x} = 0$, but here this $1 - i\omega$ factor in exponent really confuses me.

Comment: The $e^{-i \omega x}$ term is just oscillating. So you have the product of something which is bounded above and below and oscillates and something that goes to $0$.  So you can find the limit by using the squeeze/sandwich theorem $$-e^{x} \le e^{x(1-i \omega)} \le e^{x}$$ Taking $x \to -\infty$, we find the limit is $0$.

Comment: @Mattos Can you please explain why $e^{-i \omega(-\infty)} = e^{i\omega\infty}$ is bounded?

Comment: It's right there in my comment. Also, writing $e^{i \omega \infty}$ has no meaning.

Comment: @Mattos Your comments do make sense, however I have hard times comparing exponents with complex argument. You can write an answer, so I can accept it, if you wish.

Comment: Use that $e^{x(1-i \omega)} = e^{x - i \omega x} = e^{x} e^{-i \omega x}$. Then notice that at $x = 0$, $e^{-i \omega x} = 1$ attains its maximum. At $x = \pi/\omega$, $e^{-i \omega x} = -1$ attains it's minimum. Hence, **fixing** $e^{-i \omega x}$ at its maximum and minimum $\forall x$ allows us to bound $e^{x(1-i \omega)}$ by $$-1 \cdot e^{x} \le e^{-i \omega x} \cdot e^{x} \le 1 \cdot e^{x}$$ which is what I gave in the first comment. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks for your answers! Now I get it.

Comment: Just recall that $e^{i\omega x}=\cos{\omega x}+i\sin{\omega x}$, therefore, it is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} xe^{x(1 - i\omega)} = z \big(\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}xe^x\big) $$
where $z = e^{-i \omega}$